# How to link multiple HTML pages in web view from assets folder in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

Getting error `**html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()**` when trying to call another HTML file through html link inside web view from local assets folder in android studio.

Comment: Please, provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Below Code might resolve your issue

```
 webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient()
 {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                view.loadUrl(url)

                return true
        }

        // From api level 24
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {

                // Get the mailto url
                 val url = request.url.toString()

                 view.loadUrl(url)

                // Return true means, leave the current web view and handle the url itself
                return true
            }

    }
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html")
```